# calling function multiple times with different arguments

Tags: c++

I have a multiple arguments of type

```
string m_strVar1 = "var1";
string m_strVar2 = "var2";
string m_strVar3 = "var3";
// i have like above like 10 variables.


for(int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++) {
string strArg = "m_strArg";
std::stringstream lStream;
lStream << argCnt;
strArg.append(lStream.str());
cout << "first argument is " << strArg.c_str() << endl;

// call the function
func1(strArg.c_str());
}


///////////////

void func1(string& arg1) {
    // here i am expecting to access m_strVar1/2 value, depending on argument but value is not shown.
}
```

I think i am doing some thing wrong. can u please correct me. How can we achieve for calling the function with out calling 10 times with differnt values.

Comment: what you try to do here? send "var1" as parameter or what..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you're passing the *name* of the variable as a string, or something like that.

Instead use an array of strings, eg

```
string m_strVar[3] = { "var1", "var2", "var3" };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    funct(m_strVar[i]);
```